# jQuery Impromptu Tour - Opacity of Overlay

Tags: jquery, overlay, impromptu

I'm using [jQuery impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/) to show a popup box tour on my site (Example 19 at the bottom right of the page).

Is there a way to make a single container `#idOfContainer` NOT covered by the overlay? In other words, I want the entire page covered by the overlay EXCEPT the container (whatever element with the id attribute being referenced by Impromptu) that I am referencing in the tour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the z-index with jQuery when the user clicks. :)